# How to display items of linked model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have 2 models ("Offence" and "OffenceType") with a has_many relationship managed by a join table "lk_offence_types".

In the index.html.erb of "Offence" I'm not able to display an OffenceType item. (I've tried with delegation but it seems not work with has_many..)

Offence model:

```
class Offence < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lk_offence_types, inverse_of: :offence, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :offence_types, through: :lk_offence_types

    #delegate :offence_type_description, to: :offence_type
end
```

OffenceType model:

```
class OffenceType < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lk_offence_types
    has_many :offences, through: :lk_offence_types
end
```

LkOffenceType model:

```
class LkOffenceType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :offence_type, inverse_of: :lk_offence_types
  belongs_to :offence, inverse_of: :lk_offence_types  
end
```

Offence's index.html.erb:

```
<% @offences.each do |offence| %>
<tr>
<td><%= offence.offence_description %></td>
<td><%= offence.offence_types.offence_type_description %></td>
<% end %>
```

**<%= offence.offence_types.offence_type_description %> gives me an error**.
I've also tried with:
<%= offence.offence_type_description %> and other siyntaxes...

What am I missing?

(I'm using Ruby 2.3 and Rails 5.0.2)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over `offence types` as well. You may need to fix the styling, this is just to give you the idea of what's missing.

```
<% offence.offence_types.each do |ot| %>
 <td><%= ot.offence_type_description %></td>
<% end %>
```